# Looking for a more condensed version of "the world is bigger than you"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a shorter and more condensed version of the phrases "the world is bigger than you" or "this is greater than yourself/oneself." Something that keeps intact the message of becoming humble and learning that there's something larger than you and me.

Comment: How much shorter do you want it? It's already stripped of all but the essential components of that thought.

Comment: How about the Chinese idiom _The frog in the well_?

Comment: I want it to be short enough to be used as a name for something.

Comment: [_Pale Blue Dot_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot).

Comment: I suspect that "we are but a grain of sand” and "we  shall return to dust" are too long and perhaps places too much focus on our mortality. By the way, what is this something? A product, a book title, a poem? Naming things is off topic here because there cannot be a "right" answer.

Comment: Ah. Okay, where can I go to ask this question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are spoilt for choice. A few to name

**Drop in an ocean** (or 'a drop', 'drops', 'a drop in a thunderstorm' etc.)(would snowflake work? I don't know)

> [FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+drop+in+the+ocean)
>
> A tiny amount, especially when compared to a much larger one.

**Building block** ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/building%20block))

> : a unit of construction or composition especially : something
> essential on which a larger entity is based

**Small is beautiful** ([FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/small+is+beautiful))

> The belief, perspective, or mindset that things of a smaller scale are
> more aesthetically pleasing than those of a larger scale.

Single words that can be used

**Element** ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/element)) would also fit the bill, as in part of the whole.

**Iota** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iota)) A jot; a very small, insignificant quantity.

**Pixel** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pixel)) One of the tiny dots that make up the representation of an image in a computer's memory.

Comment: 'Building block' and 'Small is beautiful' I like.